# fire a callback when expo av native controls are fired/called?

Tags: react-native, expo

i'm trying to implement firebase video analytics in a video using expo-av: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/

what i want use to achieve is use a callback when native controls is called. e.g.: play, pause, next/prev 15 secs, is called by using native controls? i'm not really sure what to use, i'd need idea how to get it done as i cannot really see a sample implementation around. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You might need `onPlaybackStatusUpdate`  prop.

Please see example at https://github.com/expo/playlist-example/blob/master/App.js#L510

```
          <Video
            ref={this._mountVideo}
            style={[
              styles.video,
              {
                opacity: this.state.showVideo ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                width: this.state.videoWidth,
                height: this.state.videoHeight
              }
            ]}
            resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN}
            onPlaybackStatusUpdate={this._onPlaybackStatusUpdate}
            onLoadStart={this._onLoadStart}
            onLoad={this._onLoad}
            onError={this._onError}
            onFullscreenUpdate={this._onFullscreenUpdate}
            onReadyForDisplay={this._onReadyForDisplay}
            useNativeControls={this.state.useNativeControls}
          />
```